# Making new folder using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

Does anybody know how to create a new folder with ArcObjects?

This is what I want to do: insert a text in a TextBox and, when I run the aplication, it will create a folder with the name wroten in the TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about using ArcObjects but you can use VB.NET, see below.

```
Dim value as string
textbox1.text = value

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\" & value)) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\" & value)                
End If
```